# Why is runGitHub throwing an error on my public github repo containing a working shinyapp?

Tags: r, github, shiny

I've got a working shiny-app published (today) on a public Github repo:
I tried the line below to run the app from a script but get the following error.

```
shiny::runGitHub(repo = "<repo>",
                 username = "<username>")

# I have also tried:
# shiny::runGitHub(repo = "<username>/<repo>")

Downloading https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/archive/master.tar.gz
Error in utils::download.file(url, method = method, ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/archive/master.tar.gz'
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked came from here:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/run-shiny-app-from-github-repository/89839
The key is the argument `ref="main"`

```
shiny::runGitHub(repo = "<repo>",username = "<username >",ref="main")
```